# React persistent login with JWT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have an app I've created in React client/Express API with working Authentication. I am able to register, login, etc.

Now I am trying to add persistent login with JWT token so that if a user opens up the URL it will immediately direct them to the main page of the web app.

Fist I am exporting the token function from `src/services/api` in my Reactapp

## api.js

```
export const getToken = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
  api.defaults.headers.common.authorization = (token && `Bearer ${token}`) || '';
  return token;
};
```

I'm then passing that into App.js

## App.js

`import { getToken } from './services/api'`

and into the render method of `App.js`

```
  render() {
    //Persistent Login: Send user to dashboard if already authenticated
    const isAuthenticated = getToken()
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    }
```

The problem is that if I close the web page and open up, it is redirecting however it is going to a blank screen. There is no data in the console or in the network tab that shows any kind of error.

I am able to see the token in local storage in *Chrome > Inspector Tools > Application> Local Storage*.

```
KEY                 VALUE
authToken           someTokenLikeiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

If I remove the code in the render method of `App.js`, I am able to see my page layout.

I'm still relatively new to React and session handling. Most of the information I find online is related to React + Redux (which I haven't used yet) so I'm stuck.

Any ideas why the screen is returning blank? Any advice/solutions would be really great, thanks.

Comment: Remember to implement a refresh token mechanism.
You can read about it in JWT documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your get an infinity loop during checking

```js
render() {
    //Persistent Login: Send user to dashboard if already authenticated
    const isAuthenticated = getToken()
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    }
```

Each time when isAuthenticated === true, user is redirected to another page and the application is re-rendering. So, each time when app re-rendering it goes to check the condition and, therefore, get an infinite loop.
I think you can add an additional condition to avoid this loop.

```js
render() {
    //Persistent Login: Send user to dashboard if already authenticated
    const isAuthenticated = getToken()
    if (isAuthenticated && history.location.pathname !== "/dashboard") {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I was reading the solution at Github by @bsapaka in my first comment but this worked. The only thing I had to change was to change ```history.location.pathname``` to ```this.history.location.pathname```